# How to upgrade angular version using bower package

Tags: javascript, angularjs, version-control

I have serious problem(deletion delay) in my angular project so I tried to upgrade angular version.
I haven't got package.json file and I am using angular.min.js, angular-aria.js, angular-material.js, angular-sortable.js.
I only changed angular.min.js(1.3.9) to angular.js(1.6.5) and I get

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- compile

All the answers of stackoverflow is the case not using bower package.
Help me, I have already worked 2 weeks with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade your angular.js file you need to upgrade the rest of angular too.
The standard angular library's like angular-aria need to have always the same version as the core angular.js file.

Also angular-material.js has three dependency's:
 - angular-aria
 - angular-animate
 - angular-messages

Angular-material is a external angular plugin which is not developed by the core team so it has a different version number.

Comment: Thanks great answer, I already solved myself, and your answer is right